# `name` in angular directive Definition?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In this document about directive: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> #### Directive Definition Object
>
> The directive definition object provides instructions to the compiler. The attributes are:
>
> **name** - **Name of the current scope**. Optional and defaults to the name at registration.

I don't understand why the name is the name of current scope? What's the name at registration? If I specify a name, how to use it?

```
app.directive('aaa', function() {
   return {
      name: 'bbb',
      link: function() {
          // how and where to use the new name `bbb`
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some digging around the source code this is what I found:
It's a way to declare a separate attribute to assign a controller to the directive dynamically. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pXgrsc9mfC5VLyLGiKXM?p=preview).

The idea is to have a way to put the controller reference in a different attribute than the directive name. If the name property is not specified then the directive name will be used as the attribute.

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.directive('myDirective', [ function() {
  return {
    name : 'myController',
    controller : '@',
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function(scope, elm, attr) {
      console.log('myDirective.link');
    }
  };
} ]);

app.directive('myDirective2', [ function() {
  return {
    controller : '@',
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function(scope, elm, attr) {
      console.log('myDirective2.link');
    }
  };
} ]);

app.controller('MyDirectiveController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
  console.log('MyDirectiveController.init');
} ]);

app.controller('MyDirectiveController2', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
  console.log('MyDirectiveController2.init');
} ]);

app.controller('MyDirective2Controller', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
  console.log('MyDirective2Controller.init');
} ]);
```

Template:

```
<h1 my-directive my-controller="MyDirectiveController">My Directive Controller</h1>
<h1 my-directive my-controller="MyDirectiveController2">My Directive Controller 2</h1>
<h1 my-directive2="MyDirective2Controller">My Directive 2 Controller</h1>
```

Output:

```
MyDirectiveController.init
myDirective.link
MyDirectiveController2.init
myDirective.link
MyDirective2Controller.init
myDirective2.link
```

Comment: +20 too! So the document is quite misguidedly.

Comment: Good job on describing this feature (name attribute + ‘@’ controller value), but I wonder how supported it is. I don’t see the name attribute described in docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive as described above (must have been removed). Nor do I see this feature described in the more detailed docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile. ...I posted a question to the angular github about this and the response is that it's needed to implement ngController. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7615#issuecomment-44450165.  So, IMO, it's risky to rely on since it's undocumented.

Comment: I ran into problems following a tutorial that discussed shared controllers. I noticed the name approach wasn't documented and I couldn't get name to work in this scenario (the linked directives just wouldn't pick up the parent directive controller), so I second the advice that this is risky.

Comment: @steve Exactly because it's used in `ngController` you can pretty much abuse it to your own liking until they rewrite said directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name of the directives controller, so if you want the controller from another directive you use the new name. This is used by `ngForm` directive you must type `require:'form'` instead of `require:ngForm`.